# Resizing UIButton on 3.5inch screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have two UIButtons in my app, which are custom buttons with background images, so they look like two dice. When my app is run on something not-iPhone 5 (not 4.0 inch screen) I want the to resize the buttons. I already have the code that checks for non-iPhone 5 devices(and it works), I just need to know how to change the size of the UIButtons.
I have tried lots of answers for similar questions, but so far I have not written any code that actually changes the size of my UIButtons.
I have written something like this in the "viewDidLoad" inside my "check-if-screen-is-non-iPhone-5"-statement:

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(90, 200, 100, 100);
```

Comment: That's the way to do it, what's the problem?

Comment: If your storybord using auto-layout then turn it off and try.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on whether you're using Interface Builder or creating yoru button programatically. Most likely, you want to set the "content mode" of the button's imageView; then update the button's frame.

Here is an example:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"close"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[button.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Good luck.